# Getting a specific View from an AlertDialog's ListView

Tags: android

I am trying to make an AlertDialog that contains a list but I need some items in the list to have a different text color or background color, so I am attempting to grab the individual views of each item but it doesn't seem available.

Here is my code:

```
final String[] listItems = new String[listQuestion.size()];

for(int i=0; i<listQuestion.size(); i++) {
    listItems[i] = "" + (i+1) + ". " + listQuestion.get(i).question;
}

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setItems(listItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        currentQuestion = which;
        loadQuestion();
    }

});


outlineDialog = builder.create();

// THE LINE BELOW RETURNS NULL
//System.out.println(outlineDialog.getListView().getAdapter());

outlineDialog.show();
```

The commented line is how I was planning to grab the individual views, but the adapter returns null and if I only get the ListView, it returns something called a "RecycleListView". Any ideas? Thanks!